# SSHFS mount for digital ocean

Tags: digital-ocean, sshfs

I am using Mac OS maverick. I attempted to follow the instructions as mentioned in

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

However, after doing this

```
sudo sshfs root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ ~/mnt/droplet
```

I was unable to access the folder droplet. It disappeared from finder.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue on Snow Leopard. It's a MacFUSE issue. You need to add an extra option to tell MacFUSE to allow outside programs handle it.  Also you need to tell it to defer permission checks.

this worked for me:

```
sudo sshfs me@my.remote.server.edu:/ /Users/ME/MyMOUNT -o allow_other,defer_permissions
```

More on macfuse options here:

http://jann.is/daily/archives/757-ExtraAdvanced-options-for-MacFuseMacFusion.html

And here:
https://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/OPTIONS

And another user having same issue (resolved in a slightly different way) here:
https://superuser.com/questions/772405/why-does-directory-vanish-when-i-do-sshfs-how-to-setup-sshfs-share-on-max-osx-1